# Structuring backbone.js app with require.js

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I started following [Organizing your application using Modules (require.js](http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/) tutorial, but after adding first event handler to my view - I encountered problem:

```
// Filename: views/project/list
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'handlebars',
  'collections/projects',
  'text!templates/projects/list.js'
], function ($, _, Backbone, Handlebars, ProjectsCollection, projectListTemplate) {
    var ProjectListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#container'),
        events: {
            "click .open-proj": "openProject",
        },
        initialize: function () {
          ...
        },
        render: function () {
            ...
        },
        openProject: function(e) {
            // HERE I WANT TO TRIGGER ROUTING VIA router.navigate
            alert("opened");
        }
    });
    // Our module now returns our view
    return ProjectListView;
});
```

In the `openProject` callback I want to trigger routing, but I cannot introduce dependency to app.js as it would cause circular dependency(router depends on view). How should I handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass your router to the `ProjectListView` when you create it:

```
var projectListView = new ProjectListView({
    router: app_router
});
```

Since `ProjectListView` is a `Backbone.View`, it can then access the router using `this.options.router`, no circular dependency problem here.

Comment: Yes it might work, but I used define routing callbacks inside extend() not in initialize()

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you can access `this.options.router` from within `openProject`

Comment: I couldn't get routes to trigger when binding inside initialize(), see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582974/backbone-js-router-event-binding-not-firing So I cannot set the reouter when I create the view