# Backbone.js Router event binding not firing

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to follow [Organizing your application using Modules (require.js](http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/) I'm struggling to understand how routing works.

I cannot get simple binding to work for index:

```
// Filename: router.js
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'views/projects/list'
], function ($, _, Backbone, ProjectListView) {
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            // Define some URL routes
            '': 'index'
        }
    });

    var initialize = function () {
        var app_router = new AppRouter();

        app_router.on('index', function () {
            alert("index"); // this never gets called
        });

        Backbone.history.start();

        return app_router;
    };
    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

When page is loaded nothing happens. This however works:

```
// Filename: router.js
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'views/projects/list'
], function ($, _, Backbone, ProjectListView) {
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            // Define some URL routes
            '': 'index'
        },
        index: function() { alert("works"); }
    });

    var initialize = function () {
        var app_router = new AppRouter;

        Backbone.history.start();

        return app_router;
    };
    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, so this is how it's done:

```
    var initialize = function () {
        var app_router = new AppRouter();

        app_router.on("route:index", function () {
            alert("hello world");
        });

        Backbone.history.start();

        return app_router;
    };
```

Comment: Thanks man, I was all Friday struggling with this at work and now I've seen the light ;)

Comment: @Fdr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017210/router-js-function-not-executed Can you help me out here :) Thank you